# how can i disable a radio button on click to another radio button

Tags: jquery, html

how can i disable and enable a sub radio button on click to the another radio button using jquery.

I want to disable radio button(er_que) when i click radio button(#atten) and enable the same when i click radio button(#quest)

```
<tr>
      <td>What do you want to know?<br />
         <input name="er_1" id="atten" type="radio" value="attendence" /> Attendance<br />
         <input name="er_1" id="quest" type="radio" value="que_ask" /> Questions Asked<br />
       </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input name="er_que" type="radio" value="total" /> Total Number<br />
       <input name="er_que"  type="radio" value="issue_wise" /> Issues Wise
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name="er_1"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'attendence') {
        $('input[name="er_que"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         return;
    } 

    $('input[name="er_que"]').removeAttr('disabled');              
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('input[name="er_1"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'attendence') {
            $('input[name="er_que"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('input[name="er_que"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/eH55n/

Answer (score -1):

The following should do the trick:

```
// Disable //
$('#atten').click(function(){
    $('input[name="eq_que"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});

// Enable //
$('#quest').click(function(){
    $('input[name="eq_que"]').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: What happens when a user uses his keyboard to switch radio buttons?